# Char type in a switch statement

Tags: objective-c, macos, char, switch-statement

I was looking at an earlier experiment of mine in which your input was one character and the output would display the 'binary code', but something went wrong and I can't seem to get where the problem gets started.

This is the code:

```
char myNothing = 0;

        scanf("%c", myNothing);
        switch (myNothing)
        {
            case 'a':
                NSLog(@"01100001");
                break;
            case 'b':
                NSLog(@"01100010");
                break;
            case 'c':
                NSLog(@"01100011");
                break;
            case 'd':
                NSLog(@"01100100");
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"Unknow character");
                break;
        }

        return 0;
```

And this is the output when any character is inserted into the input:

```
Run Command: line 1:   607 Segmentation fault: 11  ./"$2" "${@:3}"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change:

```
    scanf("%c", myNothing);
```

to:

```
    scanf("%c", &myNothing);
```

Or better yet:

```
    myNothing = getchar();
```

Also, make sure you have compiler warnings enabled.

Comment: Wow, that was a bit of a dumb mistake, thanks for noting it anyway.